# Find only the real eigenvalues of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If a matrix has many (thousands) complex and  few (dozen) real eigenvalues is there a fast method for estimating only the real eigenvalues ?

Comment: Note that the characteristic polynomial is a real-valued functions whose zeros you can search for using numerical methods. Note however, that this requires you calculate a determinant every time you want one value of the function.